# WooCommerce product shortcode not working in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on wordpress shortcode. In the functions.php, I have added following code

```
add_shortcode('post-footer-note', 'getPostFooterNote');
function getPostFooterNote() {
    return "<div>Hope you find this tutorial useful! <a href='#'>Share this link</a> on Social Media.</div>";
}
```

and in the post page, I added **[post-footer-note]** The code works fine. Instead of "Hope you find this tutorial useful" text I want to display WooCommerce products. To show the products on the page, I made few changes in the code

```
add_shortcode('post-footer-note', 'getPostFooterNote');
function getPostFooterNote() {
    return "<div>[products limit="8" columns="4" category="hoodies, tshirts" cat_operator="NOT IN"]</div>";
}
```

After making changes, following error is showing.

```
Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 461 of file C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentynineteen\functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

syntax error, unexpected integer "8", expecting ";"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in:

```
function getPostFooterNote() {
    return "<div>[products limit="8" columns="4" category="hoodies, tshirts" 
cat_operator="NOT IN"]</div>";
}
```

You need to use different quotations like this:

```
function getPostFooterNote() {
    return do_shortcode("<div>[products limit='8' columns='4' category='hoodies,  tshirts' cat_operator='NOT IN']</div>");
}
```

You could also flip the quotes (it doesn't matter which is the outer quotation marks (double or single).

As per the error, the second double quote is just before the `8`, and therefore the `return` is concluded, and a semicolon is expected. Instead `8` is next, and the compiler doesn't know how to parse your code.

Edit: added @Moshe Gross' edit to final solution.

Comment: I made changes in the code. The error is fixed now. But on the post page, instead of products, shortcode is showing. https://i.imgur.com/DxMI5FE.png

Comment: You have to use `do_shortcode` like this
`return do_shortcode("<div>[products limit='8' columns='4' category='hoodies, 
tshirts' cat_operator='NOT IN']</div>");`